# What one word would describe the following word groupings?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a leader, like Narendra Modi, who is very fond of using things like,

the ‘5 Es’ of Economy, Environment, Energy, Empathy, Equity
the '3 D's' India offers, Democracy, Demography, Demand

I am hunting for a word to describe such word groupings and use it in a sentence like:

> Narendra Modi, famous for his ____ , enthralled the audience at Madison Square with his speech.

Edit: Based on WS2 and Hugh's answers, I believe the best **phrase** to describe such things would be **alliterative mnemonics** .

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that in essence they are ***mnemonics*** - devices "such as a pattern of letters, ideas, or associations which assist in remembering something" (ODO)

The usual *mnemonic* is something like the one designed to remember the order of the planets in distance from the sun - *Men very easily make jugs, (which) serve useful, necessary purposes*.

However things like Modi's *three Es* are popular as *political slogans*, or *mantras*. Tony Blair, before he became Prime Minister, made his now famous assertion that his "three main priorities for government" would be "education, education and education".

**So I don't know if there is a single one-word answer to your question, but I would suggest that the expressions you describe have elements of a *mnemonic*, a *slogan*, and a *political mantra* about them.**

Answer (score 1):

**Alliteration's Artful Aid**

> An Austrian army, awfully arrayed,
>   Boldly by battery besieged Belgrade;
>   Cossack commanders cannonading come...

The repetition of an initial letter for extra emphasis, engagement, and retention is called *Alliteration.*  Welsh poetry has a subtler form, *Cynghanedd.*